# Prove for every $a$ in $I$ and every $b$ in $J$ that $ab=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$I$ and $J$ are respectively right and left ideals of ring $R$. $I$ and $J$ have no elements in common other than $0$.  Prove  for every $a$ in $I$ and every $b$ in $J$ that $ab=0$.

I have practically no experience in making ring theory proofs.  Here is some (probably irrelevant) thoughts I have had so far:  I know the formal definition of a right (left) ideal.  We want to prove $ab=0$ for ALL $a$ in $I$ and ALL $b$ in $J$ so I think we should start by letting $a$ and $b$ be arbitrary elements in $I$ and $J$ respectively.  I have noticed that sometimes a clever notational choice of the arbitrary elements is helpful for clarity and direction in the proof.  I also have realized that if either $I$ or $J$ is $\{0\}$ then the statement is trivial so otherwise we can assume there is a nonzero element in both $I$ and $J$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in I$ and $y\in J$. Then $xy\in I$ because $I$ is a right ideal, and $xy\in J$ because $J$ is a left ideal. Since $I$ and $J$ intersect trivially, this means $xy=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple here:
$ab\in I$ since $a\in I$  and $I$ is a *right* ideal. But also $ab\in J$  sice $b\in J$  and $J$ is a *left* ideal. Thus $ab\in I\cap J=\{0\}$, so $ab=0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Just for clarity, I believe you have a typo in your penultimate equation.  You have A instead of I.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I'm fond of pytos…

Answer (score 1):

$I$ a right ideal implies $ar\in I$ for any $a\in I$ and $r\in R$ $J$ a left ideal implies $rb\in J$ for any $b\in J$ and $r\in R. Hence
$$a\in I,b\in J\implies ab\in I\cap J\implies ab=0$.